# Reshape arrays from MNIST

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, mnist

I am working with the mnist dataset and want to plot some numbers at once. This dataset provides me arrays with the shape `(784, )` and represent an image with 28x28 pixels.

Let's say I want to draw 4 numbers in a 2x2 grid. This grid should have the shape `(2*28, 2*28)`. This is the result I want:

```
+---+---+
| 0 | 9 |
+---+---+
| 9 | 0 |
+---+---+
```

This here is my code:

```
zero # an array from the mnist dataset
nine # another array from the mnist dataset

zero.shape
#(784,)
nine.shape
#(784,)

x = np.stack([zero, nine, zero, nine])
x.shape
# (4, 784)

imshow(x.reshape(2*28, 2*28))
show()
```

This is what I get:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are stacking the arrays, and then reshaping. Numpy reshapes arrays by going row-wise. The following code achieves what you want:

```
upper_layer = np.append(zero.reshape(28, 28), nine.reshape(28, 28), axis=1)
lower_layer = np.append(nine.reshape(28, 28), zero.reshape(28, 28), axis=1) 

layout = np.stack([upper_layer, lower_layer])
plt.imshow(layout.reshape(2*28, 2*28))
```

[image: Layout after using stack]

(I have used randomly generated np arrays since I did not have quick access to the MNIST data)

**What your code does:**

If you notice very carefully, the two zeros that appear side by side are not identical. What is happening is that the first 28 pixels are the first row of the `zero` array. The next 28 **in the same row** are the second row of the `zero` array. Thus it renders two zeros side by side, where the first (left) one is every even numbered pixel row (0-based index), and the right one is every odd numbered pixel row.

```
reshaped = np.stack([zero, nine, zero, nine]).reshape(2*28, 2*28)
plt.imshow(reshaped)
```

[image]

Notice how the blue values only reach 14 on the y-axis from the top, this is because it rendered two original (1x28) rows into a single (1x56) row.

Comment: ahhh, thank you very much for the explanation. That does make sense to me now.